# reuseTerm JSOM sharepoint 2013 usage

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

Anyone familiar with SP.Taxonomy.TermSetItem.reuseTerm(e, d) ? 
its there in MSDN and i guess it is to copy a termset to another termset as a sub-term.
Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`SP.Taxonomy.TermSetItem.reuseTerm` function has the following signature:

```
function SP.Taxonomy.TermSetItem.reuseTerm(sourceTerm,reuseBranch)
```

**Parameters**

- `sourceTerm` Type: [SP.Taxonomy.Term](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312546.aspx) The source Term
  for the reused Term
- `reuseBranch` Type: Boolean Reuse the [TermSetItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312643.aspx) and its child Terms

> creates a new reused Term object below this [TaxonomyItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312531.aspx) object based
>   on a sourceTerm

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to create a new reused Term object:

```
var sourceTermId = 'source-term-id-goes-here'; //Id of source Term
var targetTermId = 'target-term-id-goes-here';  //Id of Term below which a reused term will be created 

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(ctx);
var sourceTerm = taxonomySession.getTerm(sourceTermId);
var targetTerm = taxonomySession.getTerm(targetTermId);
targetTerm.reuseTerm(sourceTerm,true);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        console.log('Reused term has been created');
    },
    function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

Comment: It works Thank you. Here source and destination should not be belong to the same termset.